# Calculation for negative integer order Associated Legendre Function

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

I am currently engaging with the following hypergeometric function as a result of attempting to find [a solution for this probability problem for $n$ number of dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844908/mass-function-for-a-geometric-distribution-with-two-non-fail-outcomes):

$$_2F_1\left (\frac{n+k}{2}, \frac{n+k+1}{2};k+1;\frac{4b(d-e+1)}{d^2}\right ); \{n,k,b,d,e\}\in \mathbb{N}^+, z\in \mathbb{R},b < e \leq d$$

I'm trying to determine if there's way to calculate this function that doesn't require infinite sums (ideally, just with elementary functions and finite sums/products).

I first note that this function is of the pattern:
$$_2F_1\left (a, a+\frac{1}{2};c;z\right )$$
[DLMF 15.9.17](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.9.E17) then states that:

$$_2\bar{F}_1\left (a, a+\frac{1}{2}; c; z \right )=2^{c-1}z^\frac{1-c}{2}(1-z)^{-a+\frac{c-1}{2}}P_{2a-c}^{1-c}\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}} \right )$$

where we're using [DLMF's definition (14.7.14)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.7.E14) of:

$$P_{n}^{m}(z)=\frac{(z^2-1)^{\frac{m}{2}}}{2^nn!}\frac{d^{m+n}}{dx^{m+n}}(z^2-1)^n$$

Okay, that seems reasonable enough to plug in, and if we do, we get:

$$_2\bar{F}_1\left (\frac{n+k}{2}, \frac{n+k+1}{2}; k+1; z \right )=2^{k}z^{-\frac{k}{2}}(1-z)^{-\frac{n}{2}}P_{n-1}^{-k}\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}} \right )$$

So that leaves us with an Associated Legendre Function of negative integer order. [DLMF 14.9.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.9.E13) gives us a recurrence relation that can convert this to an ALF of positive order:

$$P_{\nu}^{-m}\left ( z \right )=\frac{\Gamma(\nu-m+1)}{\Gamma(\nu+m+1)}P_{\nu}^{m}\left ( z \right )$$

But after a lot of work I've realised that this isn't actually suitable for the problem I'm looking at, because for ALFs of integer order and degree, $P_{n}^{m}=0$ where $m>n$, and the problem I'm looking at it's quite common for $|m|>n$, so the easy method is out. I've tried looking at as much of the literature as I can understand, and so far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a known identity for $P_{n}^{-m}$ for $|m|>n$ that doesn't involve infinite sums.

So the question I am asking is: **Is there a known equation to calculate Associated Legendre Functions of arbitrarily large negative integer order and positive integer degree that doesn't require infinite sums (and, preferably, only requires elementary functions with finite sums/products)?**

Comment: To clarify: an existing library implementation of $_{2}F_{1}$, such as the [ARB library](https://arblib.org/arb_hypgeom.html#generalized-hypergeometric-function)'s `arb_hypgeom_2f1()`, or corresponding [complex-valued function](https://arblib.org/acb_hypgeom.html#gauss-hypergeometric-function), would be of no use to you, because you need to create your own implementation?

Comment: If there's a mostly-human-readable and mostly-human-computable algorithm already in existence, I'd be happy to be directed to it, but the goal isn't specifically to implement in code (there are plenty of $_2F_1$ functions in various languages that can calculate this, and Mathematica can do it even better). I want something that's mostly human-computable and can generate an exact answer. I know this *should* be possible, there are finite ALF series out there, but none seem to be appropriate for this particular problem.

Comment: Specifically: I'm building this as part of a series of Probability Mass Functions on various dice pool variations, and I'm trying to assume high-school-level-or-lower math background with the formulae.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know what "human-readable" and "human-computable" means. One can read the source code for ARB. It is open-source software and was written by a human. If you are referring to "simple" algorithms also capable of accurate computation, that gets one about as far as the error function or Lambert's W. When accurate answers are required, already something like the incomplete gamma function will result in a more challenging "complex" algorithm, let alone any of the hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate
\begin{equation}
 G={}_2F_1\left (\frac{n+k}{2}, \frac{n+k+1}{2};k+1;x \right)
\end{equation}
one can recognize the pattern
\begin{equation}
 G={}_2F_1\left (s, s+1/2;2s+1-n;x \right)
\end{equation}
where $s=(n+k)/2$. Under this form, it can be interpreted as the $n$-th derivative of a simpler hypergeometric function by [this relation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5.E4):
\begin{equation}
\frac{{\mathrm{d}}^{n}}{{\mathrm{d}z}^{n}}\left(z^{c-1}{}_2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)%
\right)={\left(c-n\right)_{n}}z^{c-n-1}{}_2F_1\left(a,b;c-n;z\right)
\end{equation}
($(.)_n$ correspond to the [Pochhamer symbols](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)). Here $a=s,b=s+1/2,c=2s+1$, then
\begin{equation}
 G=\frac{x^{n-2s}}{(2s+1-n)_n}\frac{{\mathrm{d}}^{n}}{{\mathrm{d}x}^{n}}\left(z^{2s}F\left(s,s+1/2;2s+1;x\right)%
\right)
\end{equation}
But this special hypergeometric function is [tabulated](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0126.01):
\begin{equation}
 {}_2F_{1}(s,s+{\frac{1}{2}};2\,s+1;z)=2^{2s}\left({\sqrt{1-z}}+1\right)^{-2s}
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
  G=\frac{2^{n+k}x^{-k}}{(k+1)_n}\frac{{\mathrm{d}}^{n}}{{\mathrm{d}x}^{n}}\left(z^{n+k}\left({1+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)^{-n-k}
\right)
\end{equation}
The inner function
\begin{align}
z^{n+k}\left({1+\sqrt{1-z}}\right)^{-n-k}&=\left( \frac{z}{1+\sqrt{1-z}} \right)^{n+k}\\
 &=\left( 1-\sqrt{1-x} \right)^{n+k}\\
 &=\sum_{m=0}^{n+k}\binom{n+k}m (-1)^m\left( 1-x \right)^{m/2}
\end{align}
As
\begin{equation}
 \frac{{\mathrm{d}}^{n}}{{\mathrm{d}x}^{n}}\left( \left( 1-x \right)^{m/2} \right)=(-1)^n\left( m/2+1-n \right)_n(1-x)^{m/2-n}
\end{equation}
one obtains
\begin{equation}
 G=\frac{2^{n+k}(-1)^nx^{-k}}{(k+1)_n}\sum_{m=0}^{n+k}(-1)^m\binom{n+k}m \left( m/2+1-n \right)_n(1-x)^{m/2-n}
\end{equation}
which seems to be numerically correct.