Long term probability of going bankrupt?
Suppose there is a coin flipping game where you start with 5 dollars. At each turn, there is a $p$ probability of winning 1 dollar and a $1-p$ probability of losing 1 dollar. The game ends at 0 dollars or 10 dollars.
I am trying to answer the following questions:

Question 1: At the nth turn, what is the probability of having $i$ dollars?
Question 2: How long will it take (on average) for the game to end?

I know that this problem is a version of Gambler's Ruin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin) and that there well known solutions to this problem - but I am trying to derive them myself without using the strategies used to analyze Gambler's Ruin.
Here is my attempt:
To find the probability of being at position $ i $ after $ n $ turns,  consider the number of ways we can achieve this through a combination of wins and losses. Define:

$ X_n $: Position after $ n $ turns.
$ k $: Number of wins.
$ n - k $: Number of losses.
$ p $: Probability of a win.
$ 1 - p $: Probability of a loss.
Initial position: $ X_0 = 5 $.

The position after $ n $ turns :
$$ X_n = X_0 + k - (n - k) = 5 + 2k - n $$
The probability of being at $ X_n = i $:
$$ i = 5 + 2k - n $$
Solving for $ k $:
$$ 2k = i - 5 + n $$
$$ k = \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} $$
Here, $ k $ needs to be a valid integer within the number of turns:
$$ 0 \leq k \leq n $$
Since $ k $ must be an integer:
$$ k \geq \left\lceil \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \right\rceil $$
$$ k \leq \left\lfloor \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \right\rfloor $$
Therefore, $ k $ must lie within:
$$ \max(0, \left\lceil \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \right\rceil) \leq k \leq \min(n, \left\lfloor \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \right\rfloor) $$
The probability of having exactly $ k $ wins and $ n - k $ losses is given by the binomial distribution:
$$ P(X_n = i) = \sum_{k = \max(0, \lceil \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \rceil)}^{\min(n, \lfloor \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \rfloor)} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$
This is where I get stuck: As $n$ becomes large, we need to consider all possible ways of ending up with $i$ dollars (based on the Binomial Distribution). If we don't know $n$, we have to consider all possible situations : the probability of getting to $n$ turns from there the probability of getting $k$ wins:
$$ P(X_{\infty} = i) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(N=n) \sum_{k = \max(0, \lceil \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \rceil)}^{\min(n, \lfloor \frac{i - 5 + n}{2} \rfloor)} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$
I don't know how to proceed from here. How can the limit of this infinite sum be analyzed to answer these questions?
Do we need to use Central Limit Theorem/Normal Approximation of the Binomial Distribution? Do we need to use Probability Generator Functions?

What are the winning conditions?

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/does-the-drunk-man-fall-off-the-cliff-a-random-walk-problem might help.

@ lucenaposition : please see the updates

This question might also give you some insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844908/mass-function-for-a-geometric-distribution-with-two-non-fail-outcomes

@ Lee Davis-Thalbourne : thank you! I will check it out!

I'm afraid that the summation itself has issues: It didn't consider the absorbing states of 0 and 10. Even if you find a way to compute the sum, it's still not the correct probability wanted.

Model this as a random walk on a graph. You can consider a weighted directed graph with $11$ vertices. Where $v_i$ represents having $i$ dollars. At each state there is a chance to transition from $v_i$ to $v_{i+1}$ with probability $p$ and from $v_i$ to $v_{i-1}$ with probability $1-p$. The exceptions are the terminal vertices $v_{10}$ and $v_0$ which cannot move.
You can collect this information into a matrix $M$ where the $M_{ij}$ is the probability of moving from $v_i$ to $v_j$. (I know usually you count matrix indices starting from $1$, but in this case its better to start from $0$). $M$ is 11x11, it has entries of $p$ in the super diagonal and entries of $1-p$ in the sub diagonal — except for the top and bottom rows which only have $1$ in their main diagonal entries. Pardon me for not rendering $M$ in LaTeX — it is rather large, but its structure is straightforward to describe.
Now the probability of being at state $j$ after taking $n$ steps starting from state $i$ can be calculated simply by computing
$(M^n)_{ij}$. This should answer your first question.
Now for the second question: let $T$ be the stopping time for the game. We have that, $\mathbb{E}(T) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(T > n)$. Where $\mathbb{P}(T > n) = 1- (M^n)_{5,0}-(M^n)_{5,10}$. The events of hitting zero dollars after n steps and hitting 10 dollars after n steps are mutually disjoint. The expressions for those two entries can be computed explicitly by diagonalizing M, however I expect the numbers to be very ugly.
EDIT: Taking a page out of the article. We can reorder the vertices and write
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} Q_{9 \times 9} & R_{9 \times 2} \\ 0_{2 \times 9} &I_{2 \times 2} \end{bmatrix}$$
Where $Q$ includes connections from transient states to transient states $(v_1, \dots v_9)$, $R$ represents connections from  transient states to absorbing states $(v_0, v_{10})$ and $I$ represents the   two absorbing states.
Now we can compute the stopping time in a different way:
$$(I - Q)^{-1} = \sum_{n \geq 0} Q^n $$
This is not immediately obvious but it is true that $Q$ must have all eigenvalues less than one and so this geometric series will converge. Entries of $Q^n$ represent the probability of being in a transient state after $n$ time steps (using the above representation of the expected value of stopping time), so calculating $(I-Q)^{-1}[1, 1, \dots 1 ]^T$ will give us the distribution of expected stopping times for each transient starting state.
Now we have that $I - Q$, (say $q = 1-p$ for simplicity) is a tridiagonal matrix
$$I - Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -p & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
-q & 1 & -p & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & -q & 1& -p \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & -q & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
The solution to $(I-Q)\vec{x} = \textbf{1}$ can be solved by row reduction. We could also write it as a short recurrence relation.
We have that $$-qx_{n-1} + x_n - px_{n+1} = 1$$ for $n = 0, \dots 10$ subject to boundary conditions that $x_0 = x_{10} = 0$. I'll solve the case where $p < 1/2$, when $p = 1/2$ solution is different but a little simpler to compute.
You can check that $x_n = \frac{n}{1-2p} + y_n$ is a solution if $y_n$ is a solution to the homogeneous recurrence: $y_n - py_{n+1} - qy_{n-1} = 0$ subject to $y_0 = 0$ and $y_{10} = \tfrac{-10}{1-2p}$.
You can use the standard techniques to solve the homogeneous equation, we get that $$y_{n} = c_+\lambda_+^n + c_-\lambda_-^n$$ with $$ \lambda_{\pm} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4pq}}{2p}.$$
And $c_{\pm}$ are chosen to satisfy the boundary conditions, a quick calculation shows that $$c_{+} = -c_- = \frac{10}{(\lambda_-^{10} - \lambda_+^{10})(1-2p)}.$$
Finally, the answer to your original question is
$$ x_5 = \frac{5}{1-2p} + \frac{10(\lambda_+^{5} - \lambda_-^{5})}{(1-2p)(\lambda_-^{10} - \lambda_+^{10})}$$

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

thanks, typo there.

I think I was wrong as well. A second thought seems to suggest $n\geq0$ in $\mathbb{E}(T)$?

For $p<1/2$, $\lambda_-=1$ and $\lambda_+=q/p$. So $$x_5=\mathbb{E}(T)=5\cdot \frac{1-3pq-p^2q^2}{p^5+q^5},$$which by symmetry and continuity, holds for all $0<p<1$.

@ Lee Fisher: thank you so much for your answer! Can this approach be used to derive the probability distribution of this time?

You have an answer to question 2. Zack Fisher managed to simplify the result a fair amount. For example , the expected stopping time for a game with even odds looks to be 15 turns.

You also have an answer to question 1. The probability distribution after $n$ steps and starting with $i$ dollars is the $i^{th}$ row of $M^n$.

I also give an expression for $\mathbb{P}(T > n)$, this is basically the same as the cdf of $T$.

@ZackFisher In my answer the above $x_5=\Bbb E[T]$ has a similar expression, but with $1-3pq\color{red}{+} p^2q^2$ in the numerator. This then fits the simulation value for a fair coin.

@dan_fulea You're right. That was my typo. Thanks!

Here is a way to consider the situation using a Markov chain with the states
$0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T$. (We use $T$ instead of $10$ for the last terminal state for an easy typing.)
Also let $q=1-p$ as usual.
A picture of this chain is:
$$ 
\overset 1\circlearrowleft
\boxed 0
\underset {\color{red}{0}}{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 1 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 2 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 3 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 4 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 5 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 6 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 7 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 8 
\underset p{\overset q{\leftrightarrows}} 9 
\underset p{\overset {\color{red}{0}}{\leftrightarrows}} \boxed T
\underset 1\circlearrowleft
\ . 
$$
The transition matrix $A$ and the initial distribution $e_5$ for given situation are:
$$
e_5=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\ ,\qquad
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
q&0&p\\
&q&0&p\\
&&q&0&p\\
&&&q&0&p\\
&&&&q&0&p\\
&&&&&q&0&p\\
&&&&&&q&0&p\\
&&&&&&&q&0&p\\
&&&&&&&&q&0&p\\
&&&&&&&&&&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Let $e_k$ be the row vector with only one $1$ entry for the position $k$. Then for instance $e_0A=e_0$, $e_TA=e_T$, so once in a terminal state ($0$ or $T$) at the next step (corresponding to multiplication by A$) we are also there.
Question 1 can now be answered, after $n$ turns the distribution probability is
$$
e_5A^n\ .
$$
For instance, after $10$ turns, in case of a fair coin, $p=q=1/2$ we have
$$
e_5A^{10}
=
\left[0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\right] 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{10}
\\
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{7}{64} & \frac{75}{1024} & 0 & \frac{25}{128} & 0 & \frac{125}{512} & 0 & \frac{25}{128} & 0 & \frac{75}{1024} & \frac{7}{64}
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
There is even in this case no simple formula, for instance:
$$
\begin{aligned}
e_5A^{20}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{137769}{524288} & \frac{11875}{262144} & 0 & \frac{124375}{1048576} & 0 & \frac{76875}{524288} & 0 & \frac{124375}{1048576} & 0 & \frac{11875}{262144} & \frac{137769}{524288}
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
\\
e_5A^{50}
&=\tiny
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{251838013820031}{562949953421312} & \frac{353759765625}{35184372088832} & 0 & \frac{29636962890625}{1125899906842624} & 0 & \frac{18316650390625}{562949953421312} & 0 & \frac{29636962890625}{1125899906842624} & 0 & \frac{353759765625}{35184372088832} & \frac{251838013820031}{562949953421312}
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
For a general formula we need to diagonalize $A$. In case $p=q=1/2$ the diagonal part has as elements the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is:
$$
x  (x - 1)^{2} 
 \left(x^{2} - \frac{1}{2} x - \frac{1}{4}\right)
 \left(x^{2} + \frac{1}{2} x - \frac{1}{4}\right) 
 \left(x^{4} - \frac{5}{4} x^{2} + \frac{5}{16}\right)
\ .
$$

Let us look now at Question 2, which has the following simple way to attack. It is the same as in the answer of Lee Fisher, well, i am trying to solve the associated linear algebra problem as simple as possible.
Denote by $x_k$ the average number of steps to reach a terminal state ($0$ or $10=T$) when starting in $k$.
Then of course $x_0=0$, $x_T=0$, and else we have the linear system:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= 1\color{gray}{+qx_0}+px_2\ ,\\
x_2 &= 1+qx_1+px_3\ ,\\
x_3 &= 1+qx_2+px_4\ ,\\
x_4 &= 1+qx_3+px_5\ ,\\
x_5 &= 1+qx_4+px_6\ ,\\
x_6 &= 1+qx_5+px_7\ ,\\
x_7 &= 1+qx_6+px_8\ ,\\
x_8 &= 1+qx_7+px_9\ ,\\
x_9 &= 1+qx_8\color{gray}{+px_T}\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Let $E_k$ be the equation for $x_k$. It has the following interpretation.
Since $k$ is not terminal, there is at least one step till the end.
After this one step we land in $k\pm1$ with probabilities $p,q$ (for $+$ and $-$ respectively), and from there we have in average $x_{k\pm1}$ steps.
To eliminate $x_1$ we do the following. Consider the first two equations, $E_1,E_2$. $x_1$ appears in them and only in them (on different sizes). Multiply the first equation, $E_1$ by $q$. Add them, $qE_1$ and $E_2$. Then $x_1$ is eliminated. (Do the same at the end, build $E_8$, $pE_9$, and add them.) In the result $qE_1+E_2$ look at the coefficient of $x_2$, then also in $E_3$. It turns out that we have to use the factors $q$, and  $(1-pq)$. In terms of $E_1,E_2,E_3$ we thus use the factors $q^2,q,(1-pq)$. (Do the same at the end using the factors $p^2,p,(1-pq)$ for $E_9,E_8,E_7$.
This process continues two more steps, because of the symmetry, and we already obtain $x_5$, all other variables are eliminated. Explicitly:
We multiply all
the above equations $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4,E_5,E_6,E_7, E_8,E_9$ respectively by
$$
q^4,\ q^3,\ q^2(1-pq),\ q(1-2pq),\ \boxed{\ 1-3pq+p^2q^2\ },\  
p(1-2pq),\ p^2(1-pq),\ p^3,\ p^4\ .
$$
Then we add.
Only $x_5$ survives.
And the equation in $x_5$ is:
$$
(1-3pq+p^2q^2)x_5 =
(p^4+q^4)+(p^3+q^3)+(p^2+q^2)(1-pq)+(p+q)(1-2pq)+(1-3pq+p^2q^2)
+
2pq(1-2pq)x_5\ .
$$
(It is a symmetric formula in $p,q$.)
A first simplification is
$$
(1-5pq+5p^2q^2)x_5 =
((1-2pq)^2-2p^2q^2)+(1-3pq)+(1-2pq)(1-pq)+(1-2pq)+(1-3pq+p^2q^2)\ ,
$$
and it gives a formula for $x_5$ as a fraction using only terms in $1,pq,p^2q^2$:
$$
x_5=\frac
{5(1-3pq+p^2q^2)}
{1-5pq+5p^2q^2}\ .
$$
It is not "homogeneous" in $p,q$, but if we want such a formula, we may
replace $1$ by $1^4=(p+q)^4$ and $pq$ by $pq(p+q)^2$ to obtain
$$
x_5=
5\cdot\frac
{p^4+p^3q+p^2q^2+p^3q+q^4}
{p^4-p^3q+p^2q^2-p^3q+q^4}
=
5\cdot\frac
{(p^5-q^5)/(p-q)}
{(p^4+q^5)/(p+q)}
\ .
$$

Computer simulation:
I am using sage. $10^5$ trials. Lazy implementation. Fair coin.
import random
N = 10^5
steps = 0 # so far, but we add

for trial in range(N):
    state = 5
    while state not in (0, 10):
        state += random.choice([-1, +1])
        steps += 1

print(f"Average number of steps this time: {(steps/N).n()}")

And the result is:
Average number of steps this time: 24.9387600000000

which is consistent with the formula
$$
x_5=
5\cdot\frac
{p^4+p^3q+p^2q^2+p^3q+q^4}
{p^4-p^3q+p^2q^2-p^3q+q^4}
\ .
$$
(Inserting $p=q$ leads to $X_5=5\cdot\frac{1+1+1+1+1}{1-1+1-1+1}$.)
